# How to use if(!Test.isRunningTest()){} for a specific test

Tags: apex, unit-test, callout, scheduled-apex

I have a class with a callout and a unittest mock for the callout. The callout has a scheduler. If I create a unittest for the scheduler the scheduler tries to do a callout If i use if(!Test.isRunningTest()){ for the scheduler my Callout unittest also are advoided to test the callout.

How do I solve this? So how to test scheduler with a callout method?

Class A

```
public class or_service { 
 @future(callout=true)
  public static void  getGuests() {
    if(!Test.isRunningTest()){     
     ...callout
    }
  }
}
```

Test Class A

```
@isTest
private class or_serviceTest {
    private static testMethod void testGetGuests() {
      .. mock
    }
}
```

Class Scheduler

```
global class or_guestsSchedulable implements Schedulable{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) 
    {        
   or_service.getGuests();
    }    
}
```

Unittest Sheduler

```
    @isTest
private class or_guestsSchedulableTest {
   private static testMethod void or_guestsSchedulableMethodTest() {
    String CRON_EXP = '0 0 23 * * ?';
    Test.startTest();
          String jobId = System.schedule('Sample_Heading', CRON_EXP, new or_guestsSchedulable());  
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the sequence of operations here? You have Class A, that you're testing, that makes a callout. Is Class A `Schedulable`? Or what is the `Schedulable` class and how is it related to Class A?

Comment: @DavidReed I updated my question to be more clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use Test.isRunningTest selectively like that. If you're in a test, it returns true. The most simple way of controlling this is a unit-test only variable that is set when necessary.

```
public class SomeClass {
  @TestVisible static Boolean doCallout = true;
  ...
  if(doCallout) {
    ...
```

---

```
@isTest class SomeClassTest {
  @isTest static void testWithCallout() {
    ...
    Test.startTest();
    Test.setMock(...);
    SomeClass controller = new SomeClass();
    controller.execute(...);
    ...
  }
  @isTest static void testWithoutCallout() {
    ...
    Test.startTest();
    // Skip callouts
    SomeClass.doCallout = false;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks this seems like te solution. If my callout is in a method how would I set the variable: SomeClass.Somemethod.doCallout = false;?

Comment: @Thomas no, you can't modify method variables. It will need to be either a static or class variable (I usually prefer static variables for ease of use, but this is not a strict requirement).

Comment: Maybe my question wasnst clear. can I do the following: public class or_service { 
@TestVisible Boolean doCallout = true;
@future(callout=true)
public static void  getGuests() { get doCallout?

Comment: @Thomas you can't access non-static members from a static method; it would need to be static.